# Check if a key exists in a Python list

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

Suppose I have a list that can have either one or two elements:

```
mylist=["important", "comment"]
```

or

```
mylist=["important"]
```

Then I want to have a variable to work as a flag depending on this 2nd value existing or not.

What's the best way to check if the 2nd element exists?

I already did it using `len(mylist)`. If it is 2, it is fine. It works but I would prefer to know if the 2nd field is exactly "comment" or not.

I then came to this solution:

```
>>> try:
...      c=a.index("comment")
... except ValueError:
...      print "no such value"
... 
>>> if c:
...   print "yeah"
... 
yeah
```

But looks too long. Do you think it can be improved? I am sure it can but cannot manage to find a proper way from the [Python Data Structures Documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

What about:

```
len(mylist) == 2 and mylist[1] == "comment"
```

For example:

```
>>> mylist = ["important", "comment"]
>>> c = len(mylist) == 2 and mylist[1] == "comment"
>>> c
True
>>>
>>> mylist = ["important"]
>>> c = len(mylist) == 2 and mylist[1] == "comment"
>>> c
False
```

Answer (score 48):

You can use the `in` operator:

```
'comment' in mylist
```

or, if the *position* is important, use a slice:

```
mylist[1:] == ['comment']
```

The latter works for lists that are size one, two or longer, and only is `True` if the list is length 2 *and* the second element is equal to `'comment'`:

```
>>> test = lambda L: L[1:] == ['comment']
>>> test(['important'])
False
>>> test(['important', 'comment'])
True
>>> test(['important', 'comment', 'bar'])
False
```

Answer (score 18):

Use `in` operator:

```
>>> mylist=["important", "comment"]
>>> "comment" in mylist
True
```

Ah! Missed the part where you said, you just want `"comment"` to be the 2nd element. For that you can use:

```
len(mylist) == 2 and mylist[1] == "comment"
```