# how prevent errors with look ahead

Tags: python

Recursively into a loop, i need to extract the value of a specific key from different dictionaries called into the loop.
The key register might be present or not inside the retrieved dictionary. When not present, my query to such key , return an error: `KeyError: 'c'`

```
dict2 ={'a':[1,2,3,4],'b':[5,6,7,8]}
dict1 ={'a':[1,2,3,4],'b':[5,6,7,8],'c':[9,9,1,3]}
lis = [dict1,dict2]
for tmp in lis:
    my_var = tmp['c']
```

At 1st loop, I correctly obtain the vector `[9,9,1,3]`; at the second the error.

Which could be a built in function to evaluate ahead `tmp['c']` before execute it and get the error ?  thks

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18084331/17517286

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. `dict2` doesn't contain a key `c`, so why are you surprised that it throws a `KeyError`? You'd get this error _any time_ you try to access a key that doesn't exist. Did you mean to ask _how to check if this key exists?_ or _how to avoid an error if it doesn't exist?_ or _how to ignore the error?_

Comment: Note: This isn't recursion

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing to "look ahead" for since you are currently "at" the element you want to check.

If you are looking for something that doesn't throw any exception, You can use `.get()`, which returns None rather than an Exception

```
for tmp in lis:
    my_var = tmp.get('c')
    if my_var is None:
        continue
```

Otherwise, use a `try/except` around `tmp['c']`

Comment: Thanks OneCricketeer , Solved ! Now I can manage the chooses with if then else.. Despite your colleague had try to answer in a polemic fashion, you straight the point. Thks